# How to escape slashes in git filter

Tags: git, sed

I'm trying to delete all lines with comments in a file from a commit with `git`'s `filter`. Concerned `.git/config` file looks like this:

```
[filter "printlnignore"]
    clean = sed '/\/\//d'
    smudge = cat
```

I want to escape the slashes with backslashes, I can see that the `sed` command is well-formed, since it works in shell. But here in git, it will not parse the config and fails on any command like `git status` with:

```
fatal: bad config file line 14 in .git/config
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to double escape backslashes, I suppose, but not sure, that will be because of the double parse of reading from file and later executing it. An issue that doesn't happen directly from the shell. The instruction will be: `clean = sed '/\\/\\// d'`

I work in Linux, but I did a test and worked, see it:

```
mkdir myproject
cd myproject
git init
echo -e "line one\n//line two\nline//three\nline four" > file.txt
echo -e "*.txt filter=myfilter" >> .git/info/attributes
vim .git/config
cat .git/config
```

That yields:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true

[filter "myfilter"]
        clean = sed '/\\/\\// d'
        smudge = cat
```

Continue with the test:

```
git add .
git commit -m "First commit"
rm file.txt
git checkout file.txt
cat file.txt
```

That yields:

```
line one
line four
```

Both lines with double slash were deleted with the `sed` command.